# Irreducible Complex Representations of the cyclic group over its group algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory

I want to work on $C_5 = \{\bf 0,\bf 1,\bf 2,\bf 3,\bf 4\}$, I know from theory that all complex irreducible representations are subrepresentations of the regular representation on the group algebra $\mathbb C [C_5]$ but I want to work them out explicitly.

$C_5$ acts on $\mathbb C [C_5]$ by cycling the coefficients, so I believe that the only invariant subspace would be that spanned by $\bf 0 + \bf 1 + \bf 2 + \bf 3 + \bf 4$.

I think we need to apply a change of basis to make the group action diagonal but I'm not sure what the new basis would be and I don't know how we would find the subrepresentations at that point.

Comment: Do you want to work them out explicitly as subrepresentations of the regular representation? And if so, why in particular do you want to do that?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft I'm just learning this theory from results I found on google, and I got really interested in question 6 here https://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/study/II/RepresentationTheory/2012-2013/Mich2012ex1.pdf but have not managed to solve it myself

Comment: I would be interested in seeing all irreducible representations of C_5 without relation to the group algebra

Comment: So there are indeed two ways to proceed. If you want a direct way, note that sending $1$ to any $5$'th root of unity gives a $1$-dimensional representation. And different roots give different ones, and hence all the five there are.

Comment: The irreducible representations of a cyclic group $C = \langle g \rangle$ of order $n$ are all $1$-dimensional, and there are exactly $n$ of them. They can be described explicitly by letting $g$ act by $\exp(2 \pi i m/n)$ for any $m = 0,\ldots,n-1$.

Comment: If you use this information and consider the matrix of the action of $1$ on the regular representation, then you already know the eigenvalues (by the above), so you can use these to diagonalize it.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft I have got the matrix (it's just a cyclic permutation matrix) and I believe that we can diagonalize it to a matrix with diagonal 1, w, w^2, ... but im not sure what to do next. Thank you for the guidance!